# how to remove @netlify/plugin-nextjs

Tags: netlify

It is said here [Cannot deploy Next.js to Netlify. Deploy failed due to an error in @netlify/plugin-nextjs plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831067/cannot-deploy-next-js-to-netlify-deploy-failed-due-to-an-error-in-netlify-plug) :

"Removing the @netlify/plugin-nextjs from the plugins tab on Netlify fixed the issue for me. I removed the plugin and triggered a new deploy."

I can't see any "plugins tab on Netlify". Where is it ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and was able to solve it by doing this:

1. Go to the Deploy Settings for your site
2. Edit the Build Settings
3. Remove the Next.js runtime and click Save
4. Edit the Build Settings, re-select Next.js, and click Save

Then, I was able to clear the cache and deploy the site.